# Unknown source sends "AT+GC" into /dev/rfcomm0 opened by BlueZ

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm testing a bluetooth application running on an Android device. I registered a dummy service on the device and opened the RFCOMM channels to it from the PC running Ubuntu 12.04:

```
bluez-test-serial 7C:E9:D3:DE:03:0A 43502780-ef1e-11e2-b778-0800200c9a66
```

It spawns `/dev/rfcomm0` alright, but immediately after I'm catching channel input on the device side. It reads `AT+GC`. Surprisingly, it seems to happen only the first time after I login.

I grepped through the BlueZ sources to no avail.

Does anybody know what could be the source of this unsolicited AT command being fed into the channel?

Comment: `AT+GC` belongs to the [V.250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set#V.250) `AT+G` series which is *Generic issues such as identity and capabilities*. So without knowing the exact meaning of the command, it's probably trying to identify the modem or its capabilities. I don't know anything about what might be issuing it, but maybe that'll help you track it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program sending it is `modem-manager`. I ran into this issue with it too. I never figured out how to make it ignore my device, so I just uninstalled the program. Not sure if that is an acceptable solution for you or not.

Comment: Fair enough, buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but in case anyone ends up here via Google, a straightforward solution that worked for me was to create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-rfcomm.rules` with the following content:

```
# ignore rfcomm0 device for now
KERNEL=="rfcomm0", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

ModemManager will ignore the device in the future. Note: this is a catch-all rule that will match any rfcomm device, so if you actually want to use one as a modem in the future, you would have to disable the rule again.

Comment: Or move that rule to 98 and make a new 99 that re-enables MM.